# Creating calendar application in C++ efficiency structure

Tags: c++, qt, calendar

I'm creating a calendar app in Qt/C++ and I'm deciding how to make the structures.

What I do so far: create sorted vector of appointments (sorted on ascending begin date).

I'm wondering if it can improve the performance if I add a std::map with 52 places (1 for every week) and in each spot a vector of the pointers to appointments during that week. Getting the appointments of e.g. January would happen in constant time (sort of - taking all the pointers of the first 4 weeks). Disadvantages: every time the user edits/removes/creates an appointment this table has to be reconstructed.

I can also just use the vector and search for the first appointment that starts in January and then look for the last one in January. This would then happen in linear time (N).

I'm guessing that when a user quickly clicks through all the months it's more efficient to have a map-table that can quickly fill the appointments for each month he clicks through, than iterating through the vector from start to end.

Maybe I could keep iterators for each month from my vector?

Any advice? - also excuse me if I placed this in the wrong stack.

Comment: The most obvious structure to me is a sorted list of appointments per day, with a vector of days in a vector of months. Is there some reason this would not suit your purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not going to use a database, you can try using one big `std::map<time_t, Appointment>` (instead of `time_t`, you can also use some other time type that can be easily compared). `std::map` will keep your appointments sorted as they are inserted. Insertion/lookup/erasing only takes logarithmic time.

When you need to list appointments within a range (say, in January 2012), use `std::map::equal_range` and supply a comparison functor that looks only at the month (or week, or day). Note that `std::map::equal_range` is also of logarithmic complexity. Once you have a pair of iterators to the equal range, traversing is constant time for each result.

If there can be duplicate appointments that have the same start time, you'll need to use a `std::multimap` instead.

---

As a general "best practice" guideline, you should strive to store your date/times in a compact numeric format (like `time_t`), and only convert for input/output purposes. It's the same rationale as storing/computing numeric values as int, float, etc, and only formatting them as a string for input/output purposes. If you want to use a convenient date/time wrapper class (with easy access to days, hours, minutes, etc), then check out the [Boost.DateTime](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/date_time.html) library or C++11's [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono). Those date/time wrappers should already define `operator<`, so they can be directly used as the key type in `std::map`.

Comment: Let's say that I use the tm-struct to define my time, giving me quick access to month, day, etc... Is it more performant to create a comparison function for the tm or simply convert the tm to time_t and compare those?

Comment: @TheDudeAbides, my gut feel is that there will many more comparisons than conversions. If performance really matters, you can try both ways and benchmark. Also see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using balanced binary-search-trees with keys (Year,Month,Day) and with values as list/vectors of appointments. It should give you `O(logn)` complexity in accessing days. AFAIR  `std::map` and `std::set` (and of course `std::multiset`) are implemented as RB (or AVL) balanced binary trees. You should be cautious, though - these structures have a much bigger constant of efficiency, so you have to benchmark your app.